# How to wrap ag-grid-react into component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid-react

I'm using React with Redux. I have a table which is made with ag-grid for react. 
Table data can be edited in line and saved.

**How to create wrapper component for that table? I need to have multiple tables with same functionality just with different data.**

In ag-grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-redux-integration-pt1/) it shows how to implement with redux store and reducers, but this solution only works with one table, because we have only one state per app. I don't want to dublicate my code just because i have two different lists of data...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example

```
// Grid.jsx
import React, {
    PureComponent,
} from 'react';

import {
    AgGridReact,
} from 'ag-grid-react';

class Grid extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        columnDefs : [],
        rowData : []
    };


    /**
     * This will set your internal columnDefs & rowData
     * from the props being passed in
     * <Grid columnDefs={columnDefs} rowData={rowData} />
     */

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {

        const {
            columnDefs,
            rowData,
        } = nextProps;

        return {
            columnDefs,
            rowData,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {
            columnDefs,
            rowData,
        } = this.state;

        return (

            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
                rowData={rowData}

            />
        );
    }
}

export default Grid;

// ExampleImpl.jsx
import Grid from './Grid';
class ExampleImpl extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        // Assuming you got these from the connect
        const rowData: [
            {
              name: "Ireland",
              continent: "Europe",
              language: "English",
              code: "ie",
              population: 4000000,
              summary: "Master Drinkers"
            },
          ];
        const columnDefs: [
            {
              headerName: "Name",
              field: "name",
              cellRenderer: countryCellRenderer
            },
            {
              headerName: "Continent",
              field: "continent",
              width: 150
            },

            {
              headerName: "Language",
              field: "language",
              width: 150
            }
        ];
        return <Grid
            rowData = {rowData}
            columnDefs = {columnDefs}
        />
    }
}

export default connect(ExampleImpl);

// ExampleImplII.jsx
import Grid from './Grid';
class ExampleImplII extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        // Assuming you got these from connect
        const rowData: [
            {
              name: "Ireland",
              continent: "Europe",
              language: "English",
              code: "ie",
              population: 4000000,
              summary: "Master Drinkers"
            },
          ];
        const columnDefs: [
            {
              headerName: "Name",
              field: "name",
              cellRenderer: countryCellRenderer
            },
            {
              headerName: "Continent",
              field: "continent",
              width: 150
            },
            {
              headerName: "Language",
              field: "language",
              width: 150
            }
        ];
        return <Grid
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
        />
    }
}

export default connect(ExampleImplII);
```

This way you have 1 presentational component and 2 container components (smart components) which know how to fetch the data and just pass it to your presentational component.

Comment: Thanks, for quick answer. I have tried something like that. But i have custom cell editors for columns "cellEditorFramework", when I change value i need to change state and after state change ag-grid decides to re-render it self :( Or maybe i missing something